# ORACLE SQL PASSWORD FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to create a function that verifies a password (more than 5 characters, different from the previous one, it isn't neither "password" nor "123456")
I tried this but i get errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_verification_function (
    username VARCHAR2, 
    password VARCHAR2, 
    old_password VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS 
BEGIN 
    IF LENGTH(password) < 6 THEN RETURN FALSE; 
    ELSE IF (password = "password" OR password = '123' OR password = old_password) THEN RETURN FALSE                                 
    ELSE RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
END my_verification_function;$
```

Comment: `OR password =  ` ?? There is also no `else if`. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391 and "password"`` refers to a column or variable. String constants need to be put in single quotes.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in database when it can directly be done at the UI/front-end level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_verification_function (
    username VARCHAR2, 
    pass VARCHAR2, 
    old_password VARCHAR2)
RETURN varchar2   IS 
BEGIN 
    IF LENGTH(pass) < 6 THEN RETURN 'FALSE'; 
    ELSIF (pass = 'password' OR pass = '123456' OR pass = old_password) THEN RETURN 'FALSE';
    ELSE RETURN 'TRUE';
    END IF;
END;
```

Several notes:

1) You should use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`

2) If you need call this function in "pure" SQL, `BOOLEAN` type will give you error, so you can use `VARCHAR2` instead.

3) Don't use reserved words like `PASSWORD`

Comment: Thanks!
I now need to create a PROFILE using this function, so i use
   PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION my_verification_function;
But i keep getting this error:
    ORA-28004: invalid argument for function specified in   my_verification_function

Comment: I never created PROFILE, I don't have any experience in that way, sorry but I can't give any advice in this case

Answer (score 2):

It should be done like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_verification_function (
   username VARCHAR2, password VARCHAR2, old_password VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN AS
BEGIN

   IF LENGTH(password) < 6 THEN 
      RETURN FALSE; 
   ELSIF (password = "password" OR password = '123' OR password = old_password) THEN 
      RETURN FALSE                                 
   ELSE 
      RETURN TRUE;
   END IF;
END my_verification_function;
/

alter profile default limit password_verify_function my_verification_function;
```

Parameter name `USERNAEM` and `PASSWORD` seems to be no problem, since Oracle  provided default function (located in `ORACLE_BASE/ORACLE_HOME/RDBMS/ADMIN/UTLPWDMG.SQL`) uses them also.